# What is the proper way to manage multiple python versions?

Tags: ubuntu, python, command-not-found

I have a machine with Python 2.6 installed as the default Python. Then, I installed Python 2.7, and manually created /usr/bin/python as a symlink to the new installation.

Then, I was [running into problems with command-not-found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9580/why-is-this-python-error-message-generated-whenever-i-type-a-nonsense-command/9585#9585). I'm trying to reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get remove command-not-found
```

and I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/python does not match the
python default version. It must be
reset to point to python2.6
```

But I really want Python 2.7 to be the default. How do I fix this mess?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Changing the default Python (or Perl, etc) on an OS is *really* bad idea. This interpreter is actually part of the OS and there may well be other OS components that are written specifically to work with that version of the interpreter.

For example on Redhat the yum tool that performs system software updates is a python application. You really don't want to break this. Such applications may depend on specific, perhaps non standard, python modules being installed which the version you installed may not have. For example on Ubuntu I believe some of the built-in OS tools written in Python use an ORM called Storm that isn't part of the Python standard library. Does your clean Python 2.7 install have the specific expected version of the Storm module installed? Does it have any version of Storm? No? Then you've just broken a chunk of your OS.

The right way to do this is install your preferred version of python and set up your user account to use it by setting up your .bash_profile, path and such. You might also want to look into the virtualenv module for Python.

Comment: Googled my way here. Would -1 if I had the rep on this stack. Why? Because the suggested approach says only "install your preferred version of python". **How** is that done without hosing the system python?

Comment: @jez Users should refer to the installation instructions for their application and OS combination of choice. In general language installer packages will install to a benign location, not overwrite core OS components so overwriting the OS version would be the special case.

Answer (score 11):

**pyenv**

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Pyenv allows you to manage multiple Python versions without sudo for a single user, much like [Node.js NVM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594656/how-to-install-the-latest-versions-of-nodejs-and-npm/971612#971612) and [Ruby RVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812471/is-there-a-python-equivalent-of-rubys-rvm/59268119#59268119).

Install Pyenv:

```
curl https://pyenv.run | bash
```

Then add to your `.bashrc`:

```
export PATH="${HOME}/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

Find Python version to install:

```
pyenv install --list
```

Install the python version you want:

```
# Increase the chances that the build will have all dependencies.
# https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems
sudo apt build-dep python3
sudo apt-get install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev \
  libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev \
  xz-utils tk-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev python-openssl git

# Build and install a Python version from source.
pyenv install 3.8.0
```

List available Python versions:

```
pyenv versions
```

We now have:

```
* system (set by /home/cirsan01/.pyenv/version)
  3.8.0
```

Select a different python version:

```
pyenv global 3.8.0
python --version
python3 --version
```

Both output:

```
Python 3.8.0
```

We can now proceed to install and use packages normally:

```
pip install cowsay
python -c 'import cowsay; cowsay.tux("Python is fun")'
cowsay 'hello'
```

We can confirm that everything is locally installed in our clean environemnt with:

```
python -c 'import cowsay; print(cowsay.__file__)'
which cowsay
```

**Per project usage**

In the previous section, we saw how to use pyenv in a global setup.

However, what you usually want is to set a specific python and package version on a per-project basis. This is how to do it.

First install your desired Python version as before.

Then, from inside your project directory, set the desired python version with:

```
pyenv local 3.8.0
```

which creates a file `.python-version` containing the version string.

And now let's install a package locally just for our project: TODO: there is no nice way it seems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30407446/pyenv-choose-virtualenv-directory/59267972#59267972

Now, when someone wants to use your project, they will do:

```
pyenv local
```

which sets the Python version to the correct one.

Related threads:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/682869/how-do-i-install-a-different-python-version-using-apt-get
- [What is the proper way to manage multiple python versions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9711/what-is-the-proper-way-to-manage-multiple-python-versions)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960805/apt-get-install-for-different-python-versions/59268046#59268046

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04, pyenv 1.2.15.

Answer (score 9):

> How do I fix this mess?

Nothing more than reinstalling **`python`**. It will undo your change (the symlink).

Why do you want it as default? Each time you need it, just use `python2.7` or include `#!/usr/bin/python2.7` (the shebang) at the beginning of your (executable) scripts.

If you insist on having **`python2.7`** as system-wide default, use a later release of Ubuntu (currently it's Ubuntu 11.04, codenamed Natty). It uses that version as default.

In future, avoid doing manual interventions like what you did with the symlink thing. This is especially true for distro-managed files, and most especially for complex beasts like Python installations.

Comment: I thought that it's only reasonable to change the default python installation once I upgraded. I want it as default because I want to work with the newer python ... as default. When I type `python` from bash, I want to get the new python. Is there a better way to do this than what I did?

Comment: Just to note - I don't think there was anything wrong in the way I installed python 2.7. The only "unorthodox" move was changing the symlink, which I thought was _the proper way_ to set it as default. Is there a better way?

Comment: @ripper234: No it's not the proper way. You see, there is a package called simply as `python`, and it's the one that determines what's the system default. In Ubuntu 10.10, that packages decides that 2.6 is default, and in Ubuntu 10.04, it decides default to be 2.7. It does more than just changing symlinks too. This remove the need to fiddle with symlinks :)

Comment: You mean Ubuntu 11.04, not 10.04, right? I'm still not grocking how releases work - it's weird to have to upgrade an entire OS just for me to change the default python installation.

Comment: @ripper234: Yes, I mean that.

Comment: @ripper234: It's that way because a Python installation is a complex thing. There is all the manner of potential problems if you start inter-mixing the versions.

Comment: @ripper234: Also, why don't you just create an alias: `alias python='python2.7'`. I myself prefer python3, so I have: `alias py='python3`.

Comment: OK, to resolve I recreated the symlink to point to python 2.6. I still don't understand it, but it works - I'll refer to 2.7 explicitly when I need to / use alias.

Comment: @ripper: I guess I'm coming to this thread a little late. As Tshepang says the `python` package on Ubuntu determines the system version. Now, it is possible to customize your installation so python 2.7 is default by creating your own python package etc, but if so, you'll effectively be becoming maintainer of your Python installation instead of Ubuntu, and you'll have to learn how Python is managed on Debian/Ubuntu. Bear in mind that the other Python packages in the system are configured to work with 2.6 as default, so, apart from anything else, breakage may result.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: i.e. fiddle only if u know what u r doing

Comment: @Tshepang: Good summary!

Comment: @ripper234: Don't change anything in `/usr/bin`, that's reserved for your distribution. Instead, make `/usr/local/bin/python` a symbolic link to `python2.7`. Then scripts using `#!/usr/bin/env python` (the recommended idiom), as well as typing `python` on the command line, will run Python 2.7. Scripts from the distribution that want the Python from the distribution can keep calling `#!/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: @Gilles: I've found at least one distro-provided package that uses `#!/usr/bin/env python`. So, I wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: @Tshepang: Most distro-provided packages won't mind a more recent version, so it's ok for them to be executed with your own, more recent Python.

Answer (score 2):

i just posted this same answer to stack overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions/50319252

(see that one for a more up-to-date answer)

Here is my take on the problem.  Works for Python3.  The main features are:

- Each Python version is compiled from source
- All versions are installed locally
- Does not mangle your system's default Python installation in any way
- Each Python version is isolated with virtualenv

The steps are as follows:

1. If you have several extra python versions installed in some other way, get rid of them, e.g., remove *$HOME/.local/lib/python3.x*, etc. (also the globally installed ones).  Don't touch your system's default python3 version though.
2. Download source for different python versions under the following directory structure:

   ```
   $HOME/
       python_versions/ : download Python-*.tgz packages here and "tar xvf" them.  You'll get directories like this:
         Python-3.4.8/
         Python-3.6.5/
         Python-3.x.y/
         ...
   ```
3. At each "Python-3.x.y/" directory, do the following (do **NOT** use "sudo" in any of the steps!):

   ```
   mkdir root
   ./configure --prefix=$PWD/root 
   make -j 2
   make install
   virtualenv --no-site-packages -p root/bin/python3.x env
   ```
4. At "python_versions/" create files like this:

   ```
   env_python3x.bash:

   #!/bin/bash
   echo "type deactivate to exit"
   source $HOME/python_versions/Python-3.x.y/env/bin/activate
   ```
5. Now, anytime you wish to opt for python3.x, do

   ```
   source $HOME/python_versions/env_python3x.bash
   ```

   to enter the virtualenv
6. While in the virtualenv, install your favorite python packages with

   ```
   pip install --upgrade package_name
   ```
7. To exit the virtualenv and python version just type "deactivate"

Comment: --no-site-packages does not work with virtualenv in Ubuntu 20.04 (20.0.17). See this note: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60783839/286807

Comment: I updated my answer in the stack overflow version.  Please check it out & upvote if you like the solution.

Answer (score 0):

We put multiple python distributions on Mac and Ubuntu a lot and here are my recommendation.

1. Leave the system python unmolested: never use it.
2. If you only need one primary python distribution, download and install [Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/) from enthought.  When it installs, choose "set as my system python", and then you can install packages from Canopy's GUI package manager.

   - Canopy is also compaitble out of the box with `pip`, the PyPi package manager command that lets you install packages (eg `pip install python-twitter`)
3. If you plan to use virtual environments (ie you are developing python programs and want a dedicated clean python environment for each, with an easy means to switch between them), I'd recommend Anaconda over Canopy due for it's [virtual environment manager tool](http://www.continuum.io/blog/conda).  This will let you